# Passing a very large string array to SQL stored proc

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, node.js

I have this stored procedure which takes a String array of productids each 13 characters long eg:2345697894131, now from my backend code I can pass it as a CSV by converting my array to a CSV string. 
Thus on stored procedure I can catch it as:

```
@in_product_id VARCHAR(MAX) or maybe VARCHAR(8000)
```

And then I use split function along with IN to check for various conditions
eg:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT top 1 * FROM Table WHERE (productid IN (SELECT (value) from dbo.split(@in_product_id,','))))
```

The syntax of select query maybe incorrect.

But is this the ideal way to take in a array of ids. My concern is when the productid array is too large and exceeds MAX then I will have to trace these ids that were missed.

I need to know an ideal way to handle such inputs in stored procedure or should I limit the number of productid to be taken?

Comment: Read up on support for *Table Valued Parameters* for your clients.

Comment: TVP mentioned by @Richard is the best performing approach. Other possible solution is to use XML, but if you can use TVP then don't even look to other options

Comment: Yes that is pretty good enough for my use case, thanks @Richard, Dmitrij XML based solution may add further complexity, so I'll go by your advice of using TVP :)